# Error including netinet/in.h

Tags: c, gcc

Even after trying all orders of header file inclusion, 
I still get the error for netinet/in.h

```
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:34: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
```

I have included the following header files

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

How do I get rid of this error?
I compile with  gcc -g3 -Wall.

Comment: `netinet/in.h` tries to define `IPPROTO_IP`, which is already defined by `netinet/ip.h` in your code. if you switch the order of these 2 includes that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**netinet/in.h** doesn't have header guard so what's happening is some variable is already been defined in **netinet/ip.h** header file. try pushing **netinet/in.h** to beginning of the file.